# Question on time-Derivative of Parameter Map

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an open interval. Given a smooth map $\varphi \colon M \times I \to M$ I would like to compute
$$\frac{d}{dt}\varphi_{t^2}(\gamma(t))$$ where $\gamma \colon I \to M$ is a smooth path in $M$ and $\varphi_t := \varphi(\cdot,t)$. My attempt:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\varphi_{t^2}(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}\varphi(\gamma(t),t^2) = D\varphi(\dot{\gamma}(t),2t \partial_t) = D\varphi_{t^2}(\dot{\gamma}(t)) + 2t \partial_t \varphi(\gamma(t),\cdot).$$
I am not sure if the last step is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$f(u,v)=\varphi_u(v)$, its differential is $\partial_u\varphi_u du +D\varphi dv$

You have $f(t^2,\gamma(t))$. Its differential is $\partial f_{t} (2t)+\partial_v f\gamma'(t).$ Where $\partial_uf =\partial_u\varphi$ and $\partial_v f= D\varphi$.

This implies that ${d\over{dt}}f(t^2,\gamma,t)=\partial_{t}\varphi_{t^2}(2t)+D\phi_{t^2}(\gamma'(t))$